# An inequality of tau function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[image]

I tried by expanding 2^n -1 but it was of no use.

Can anyone please help me to solve it?

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: What is $\tau$ ?

Comment: its a function which counts the number of divisors of a number

Comment: It's basically $\sigma_0(n)$ in the sense of the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function), also often denoted by $d(n)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for any divisor $d$ of $n$, we know that $$2^d-1|2^n-1$$
so the number of divisors of $2^n-1$ must be at least the amount of divisors of $n$. This means we don't necessarily have *all* divisors of $2^n-1$, hence the *inequality* $\tau(2^n-1)\geq \tau (n)$

---

To give a quick proof of the fact that $d|n$ implies $2^d-1|2^n-1$:

Let $n=dk$, then
\begin{align}
\frac{2^n-1}{2^d-1}&=\frac{(2^d)^k-1}{2^d-1}\\
&=(2^d)^0+(2^d)^1+\cdots+(2^d)^{k-2}+(2^d)^{k-1}\\
\end{align}
and since the last line is an integer, $\frac{2^n-1}{2^d-1}$ must be an integer - thus, $2^d-d$ divides $2^n-1$.

Comment: I got it,thanks a lot.....